# Draw from random distributions so that sum of values is fixed

Tags: correlation, random-variable, random-generation

I want to draw tuples of $N$ random numbers $v_{ij}$ with $i=1,..,N$ the tuple index and $j$ the repetition of the experiment.

The sum of all random numbers in a tuple should be constant $\forall j \sum_i v_{ij}=S$.

The expectation and variance of each $i$-th index in the tuples should be known $\mathrm{E}_j(v_{ij})=e_i>0, \sum_i e_i=S$ and $\mathrm{Var}_j(v_{ij})=v_i$.

The values should be non-negative $0\le v_{ij}\le S$.

The distribution of $v_{ij}$ for each $i$ should look as normal-distributed like as possible.

I'm aware that the condition that the sum is fixed will make them not independent. If possible I would like to distribute the correlations between different indices $i$ as equally as possible.

My idea:

I draw $N-1$ binomially distributed random numbers, scale them to match $e_i$ and $v_i$, then set the last value in the tuple to $S$ minus the sum of these distributed numbers.

However, the variance of the last index value in the tuples is usually much larger than desired and difficult to set independently and I cannot guarantee that the values in the last index stay within the bounds $[0,S]$.

Example: $N=4,e_1=10,e_2=20,e_3=40,S=100$.

[image]

The answers of [Simulation involving conditioning on sum of random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113205/simulation-involving-conditioning-on-sum-of-random-variables) didn't help me because they seem to be special to the problem presented there and not applicable to my conditions.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Related (but no duplicates): [Generate uniformly distributed weights that sum to unity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14059/1352) and [How to simulate a uniform distribution of a triangular area?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/289258/1352). The [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) is also related, but it doesn't offer much flexibility, since the means and variances of all variables are linked. The [Generalized Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Dirichlet_distribution) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: In continuous case you can re-scale the Dirichlet distribution, in discrete, you can use multinomial distribution. You can also check the [multivariate logistic normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution#Multivariate_generalization)

Answer (score 2):

You can get close to what you want by using a singular normal distribution - and if you use equal variances you will get equal negative pairwise correlations.

Using the transformation method (see guy's solution here [r - pick 10 random numbers from standard normal distribution whose sum equals 5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97213/r-pick-10-random-numbers-from-standard-normal-distribution-whose-sum-equals-5) for an example), we can find the covariace matrix (I've chosen 3 as the variance)
$$ \Sigma = \pmatrix{\ \ 3 & -1  & -1 & -1 \\
                    -1 & \ \  3  & -1 & -1 \\
                    -1 & -1 & \ \ 3 & -1  \\
                    -1 & -1  & -1 & \ \ 3}.$$

Now we can use singular value decomposition (SVD) to generate the variates (see whuber's code here - [Generating samples from singular Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159313/generating-samples-from-singular-gaussian-distribution))

Modifying whuber's code to suit your problem, we have:

```
library(MASS)

# Specify the mean vector for the multinormal distribution
mu <- c(10,20,30,40)

# Use equal variances, which leads to equal correlations
# of -1/3 among all pairwise combinations
sigma <- matrix(c(3.0,-1,-1,-1,-1,3.0,-1,-1,-1,-1,3.0,-1,-1,-1,-1,3.0),4,4)    # Covariance matrix is singular

n <- dim(sigma)[1]
s <- svd((sigma + t(sigma))/2) # Guarantees symmetry
s$d <- abs(zapsmall(s$d))
m <- sum(s$d > 0)

# Generate normals in the lower dimension
n.sample <- 100000   # Number of realizations
x <- matrix(rnorm(m*n.sample),nrow=m)

# Embed in the higher dimension and apply square root
# of sigma obtained from its SVD
x <- rbind(x, matrix(0, nrow=n-m, ncol=n.sample))
y <- s$u %*% diag(sqrt(s$d)) %*% x + mu

# Prepare data for plotting
library(data.table)
x1 <- data.table(y[1,])
x2 <- data.table(y[2,])
x3 <- data.table(y[3,])
x4 <- data.table(y[4,])

# Add in label
x1$var <- 'x1'
x2$var <- 'x2'
x3$var <- 'x3'
x4$var <- 'x4' 

all <- rbind(x1,x2,x3,x4)

# Plot histograms of the four components
ggplot(all, aes(V1, fill = var)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.9)

# Check a few totals 
sum(y[1:4,1])
sum(y[1:4,2])
sum(y[1:4,10])
sum(y[1:4,n.sample])
sum(y)

# Check to see how close the empirical correlations are 
# to negative 1/3
cor(y[1,],y[2,])
cor(y[1,],y[3,])
cor(y[2,],y[3,])
```

Here is the chart:

[image: Histograms of four component random variables]

Here is output verifying the sum requirement for a few realizations and some of the empirical correlations:

```
> sum(y[1:4,1])
[1] 100
> sum(y[1:4,2])
[1] 100
> sum(y[1:4,10])
[1] 100
> sum(y[1:4,n.sample])
[1] 100
> sum(y)
[1] 1e+07
> 
> # Check to see how close the empirical correlations are 
> # to negative 1/3
> cor(y[1,],y[2,])
[1] -0.3294876
> cor(y[1,],y[3,])
[1] -0.331753
> cor(y[2,],y[3,])
[1] -0.336657
```

If you want to specify non-equal variances among your components, you will have a different covariance matrix. You will also not have equal pairwise correlations.

Part 2 - Unequal Variances

Suppose we want variances of 2, 3, 5, and 6.

If you use the following covariance matrix,

```
sigma <- matrix(c(3.7838,-0.4865,-1.3514,-1.9459,-0.4865,7.9054,-3.0405,-4.3784,-1.3514,-3.0405,16.5541,-12.1622,-1.9459,-4.3784,-12.1622,18.4865),4,4)    # Covariance matrix is singular
```

You will get the following chart:

[image: Chart with different variances]

If this is of interest, I will post more on how to find the covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out and then report back.